# Execute a method with wildcard parameters

Tags: java, generics

I am currently doing a small workflow engine for a personal project with generic parameter.

This is not elaborate, the aim is to do something with generics.

The WorkflowExecutor is the class which will execute all step of my workflow

```
public class WorkflowExecutor<U extends WorkflowCommand<T>, T extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper> {
    List<U> commands = new ArrayList<U>();

    public WorkflowExecutor<U, T> addCommand(U command) {
        commands.add(command);
        return this;
    }

    public void execute(T arg) {
        for(int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
            arg = commands.get(i).perform(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

The WorkflowCommand class is a step of my workflow :

```
public abstract class WorkflowCommand<T extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper> {
    public abstract T perform(T arg);
}
```

The WorkflowArgumentWrapper is the class which is pass to all step of a workflow. So basically this object will be modified by a workflow step and pass to the following step.

```
public class WorkflowArgumentWrappable {
}
```

And finally a container of workflow (supposed to be a singleton in the future). It contains all my workflow and I can execute them from there :

public class WorkflowContainer {

```
    private Map<WorkflowType , WorkflowExecutor<? extends WorkflowCommand<? extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper>,? extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper>> executors =
            new HashMap<WorkflowType , WorkflowExecutor<? extends WorkflowCommand<? extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper>, ? extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper>>();

    public static enum WorkflowType {
        TEST
    }

    public void init() {
        executors.put(WorkflowType.TEST, new WorkflowExecutor<WorkflowHelloWorldCmd, WorkflowHelloWorldArgument>())
            .addCommand(new WorkflowHelloWorldCmd())  // PROBLEM HERE
            .addCommand(new WorkflowHelloWorldCmd()); // PROBLEM HERE
    }

    public void execute(WorkflowType type, WorkflowArgumentWrapper arg) {
        executors.get(type).execute(arg); // PROBLEM HERE
    }
}
```

With :

```
public class WorkflowHelloWorldCmd extends WorkflowCommand<WorkflowHelloWorldArgument> {
    @Override
    public WorkflowHelloWorldArgument perform(WorkflowHelloWorldArgument arg) {
        System.out.println(arg.getCount() + " : " + arg.getSentence());
        arg.setCount(arg.getCount() + 1);
        return arg;
    }
}

public class WorkflowHelloWorldArgument implements WorkflowArgumentWrapper {
    private String sentence;
    private int count;

    public WorkflowHelloWorldArgument()  {
        this.sentence = "Hello world";
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public String getSentence() {
        return sentence;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I add my command to my executor : `'addCommand(capture<? extends tbetous.workflow.WorkflowCommand<? extends tbetous.workflow.WorkflowArgumentWrapper>>)' in 'tbetous.workflow.WorkflowExecutor' cannot be applied to '(tbetous.test.WorkflowHelloWorldCmd)'`

And I have a problem with `executors.get(type).execute(arg);` because `'execute(capture<? extends workflow.WorkflowArgumentWrapper>)' in 'workflow.WorkflowExecutor' cannot be applied to '(workflow.WorkflowArgumentWrapper)'`

I completely stuck with this. Is there a way to do what I want ? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This is the usual problem with wildcards (hence the duplicate).  It probably means that you don't actually want/need wildcards in this situation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, thanks for your help, but the post with the possible duplication does not help me. If I let just WorkflowExecutor with no wildcare, then I have warnings. I am not sure it's good not to type my executor. Do you have an advice for me ?

Comment: There is too much code here for me to reason about it (especially because I don't know what the intended behaviour is).  But basically, you cannot invoke a method `Foo.bar(U stuff)` if `U == ?`.  The fact that you want to do that means that your class should *probably* be parameterised as `WorkflowArgumentWrapper`, not `? extends WorkflowArgumentWrapper`.